# React does not render correct on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using ant design and server side render in my React project. 
My header rendered according to user authentication status. If user is authenticated appHeader is used.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Layout, BackTop, Button } from 'antd'
import LandingHeader from './_Landing/Header/LandingHeader'
import AppHeader from './Common/AppHeader'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { bool, object } from 'prop-types'

const { Content, Footer } = Layout;

class AppLayout extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
  }

  render () {
    const { children, location } = this.props

    const isLoggedIn = this.props.isAuthenticated
    let AppHeaderConditional = null
    if (isLoggedIn && location.pathname != '/' && location.pathname != '/login' && location.pathname != '/signup') {
      AppHeaderConditional = <AppHeader />
    } else {
      AppHeaderConditional = <LandingHeader />
    }

    return (
      <div className='landing-page-wrapper' data-pathname={`${location.pathname}`}>
        {AppHeaderConditional}
        <Layout>
          <Content>
            {children}
          </Content>
        </Layout>
        <BackTop>
          <Button type='primary' shape='circle' icon='up-circle-o' size='large' />
        </BackTop>
        <Footer className='footer' style={{ textAlign: 'center' }} >
          © 2017 - 
        </Footer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

AppLayout.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: bool,
  children: object,
  location: object
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(AppLayout))
```

On full page load (i mean navigating from home to member page with link ) it renders correct with className but on page refresh this class not added to header. And console log gives an error "Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a..."

I made research about this console warning but nothing helped me. I tried pure:false (https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md), and some other things but i cant solve the issue.

Comment: Who pass isAuthentified to your component? I do not see any className in the code. Could you provide more information. Looks like server does not know if user authentified

Comment: On browser console elements tab, header has not class (appHeader) but at React tab header has class "appHeader"

Comment: Edited question, added full code.

Comment: Did you check location on server and client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. All you need is below. Because somehow page renders itself second time on client, i don't know why but this the solution.

```
componentDidMount () {
   this.setState({ mounted: true })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use staticRouter on server and browserRouter on the client - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md

Comment: Thanks but client already uses BrowserRouter and the server uses StaticRouter.